# Why is this predicate false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am stumped at my professor's answer to this predicate logic. all x and y are natural numbers.

```
     ∃y∃x(x >= y)
```

I think it is true, since there is a pair $(Y, X)$ like $(1, 5)$ such that $X \geq Y$.

But my professor says it is false!

Why?

Thank you

Comment: What is P after the quantifiers ?

Comment: P means predicate

Comment: The formula makes no sense ...

Comment: : (  that's how my professor wrote it.

Comment: If this is logic then the formula makes no sense. It looks like probability. In first order logic, ">=" has no business inside the parentheses — only arguments to $P$ belong there. In order to be true or false, it has to be well-formed; it isn't. But if you deleted $P$, and used lowercase $x$ and $y$ throughout, it would be well formed and **true** the reals, the rationals, the integers.

Comment: @BrianO, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ask what the domain of discourse is; however, the formula $$\exists y \exists x (x \geq y)$$ is true in *every* nonempty domain of discourse.

Let $\mathbb{U}$ be the (possibly empty) domain of discourse. Then, $a \geq a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{U}$. If $\mathbb{U}$ is nonempty, the existence of such an $a$ is guaranteed. However, if $\mathbb{U}$ is empty, then the existence of such an $a$ is *not* guaranteed.

In most settings, only *nonempty* domains of discourse are considered. Are you aware of an exception in this case?

Comment: no, but I guess my professor is wrong about this one. Thanks!

Comment: Any time. Consider approaching your professor with your counterexample $y = 1, x = 5$. Best of luck in your studies!

Comment: I would guess that the statement is wrong but I'd further guess that your professor actually wrote or meant to write something very different.